# c# : Deserealization to DataSet

Tags: c#, json

Can anyone help with JSON string parse on C#?

I tried to reproduce the sample from https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDataSet.htm

```
string json = @"{
                'Table1': [
                      {
                       'id': 0,
                       'item': 'item 0'
                      },
                      {
                        'id': 1,
                        'item': 'item 1'
                      }
                      ]
                     }";

dataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(json);
```

I receive the exception:

> JsonConvert.DeserializeObject exception
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Member
>   'XmlSchema' was not found.
>       09-17 07:41:27.075 I/mono-stdout( 3691): JsonConvert.DeserializeObject exception
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Member
>   'XmlSchema' was not found.
>         at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo.GetElement (System.String name, System.Type& foundType) [0x00020] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
>         at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo.GetValue (System.String name, System.Type type) [0x0002e] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
>         at System.Data.DataSet.DeserializeDataSetSchema (System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context,
>   System.Data.SerializationFormat remotingFormat,
>   System.Data.SchemaSerializationMode schemaSerializationMode) [0x000f5]
>   in :0 
>         at System.Data.DataSet.DeserializeDataSet (System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context,
>   System.Data.SerializationFormat remotingFormat,
>   System.Data.SchemaSerializationMode schemaSerializationMode) [0x00000]
>   in :0 
>         at System.Data.DataSet..ctor (System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo inf
>       o, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context, System.Boolean ConstructSchema) [0x00069] in
>   :0 
>         at System.Data.DataSet..ctor (System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context) [0x00000] in
>   :0 
>         at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:lambda_method (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,object[])
>         at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateISerializable
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonISerializableContract contract,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, System.String id)
>   [0x0015b] in :0 
>         at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonCo
>       ntainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember,
>   System.Object existingValue) [0x00347] in
>   :0 
>         at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember,
>   System.Object existingValue) [0x0006d] in
>   :0 
>         at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType,
>   System.Boolean checkAdditionalContent) [0x000db] in
>   :0 
>         at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00053]
>   in :
>       0 
>         at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00000]
>   in :0 
>         at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (System.String value, System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
>   settings) [0x0002d] in :0 
>         at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings)
>   [0x00000] in :0

What is missing? Should I add any XML schema?

Comment: It is not valid JSON, JSON keys use double quotes.

Comment: Use a [JSON validator](https://jsonlint.com/) to check your JSON string first.

Comment: Thank you Willem , it is useful to know about the JSONLint, but , unfortunately, the syntax error is not the reason of the issue

Answer (score 0):

As @Willem noted in comment use double quotation (this validates [here](https://jsonlint.com/)):

```
{
    "Table1": [{
            "id": 0,
            "item": "item 0"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "item": "item 1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Following notation diagram is the description from [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/) 
[image]

Comment: Thank you Janis and Willem. Unfortunately, this is not the reason of the issue. I changed the json string to string json = "{ \"Table1\": [{ \"id\": 0 }, { \"id\": 1 } ] }"; it passes JSONLint  tool, you mentioned, but I receive the same exception.

Comment: I recommend you trying to create a new console solution and use exact same code you paseted. Here is what I did: created new console solution, copied the code form link, downloaded Newtonsoft Json package and ran it. Worked without issues also with single quote.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm using Asp.Net Core. I need to use nuget and get a latest version of Newtonsoft.Json. Maybe the application use pre-install old version of Newtonsoft.Json. After get the latest Newtonsoft.Json (v12.0.1), it works perfectly.